# How to redirect to a page after a fivestar vote in Drupal with Rules?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-fivestar

Drupal 6.22
Fivestar 6.x-1.19
Rules 6.x-1.4
These modules were the latest as of this posting.

My goal is to redirect a user to a page when they vote on a node. Should be simple enough.

I've created a rule for when a user votes on a node. No condition. I've added an action to add a message to the log to verify the rule is being triggered. Which it is. Then adding an action to redirect to the homepage (for testing). The redirect never happens. If I check the option "Immediately issue the page redirect", the ajax vote never saves and just hangs at "saving vote...".

I don't think I'm doing anything wrong and will post this to the fivestar module issues. Has anyone else had this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://drupal.org/node/252859

A "redirect to url ..." will definitely cause issues with Fivestar's AJAX voting mechanism. Here's what's happening:

What normally happens:
- User clicks on a Fivestar widget to rate.
- AJAX request is made by the current page.
- VotingAPI saves the vote.
- Fivestar generates XML and prints the page.
- The current page receives XML, then updates the voting widget with the new values.

What happens with VotingActions:
- User clicks on a Fivestar widget to rate
- AJAX request is made
- VotingAPI records the vote
- VotingActions hooks in and says "oh I'm redirecting this URL" <-- Where things go wrong
- Instead of returning XML to the calling page (which would update the votes), the original page gets back a full HTML page of wherever VotingActions redirected the page.
- Fivestar doesn't get to generate it's XML, because VotingActions has ended the execution by using a drupal_goto().

So I don't think it's a bug in either VotingActions or Fivestar, it's just a case of using two features in incompatible ways. To make this work, Fivestar would have to *not* be AJAX driven, instead reloading the page to save a vote.

Fivestar provides a nice JavaScript hook that you can use to go to the next page. If you add JavaScript to the page that contains something like this:

```
function fivestarResult(voteResult) {
    window.location.href = 'http://google.com';
}
```